# Undefined constructor (java)

Tags: java, inheritance, methods, constructor

so I have a java class called User that contains a constructor like this:

```
public class User extends Visitor {
    public User(String UName, String Ufname){
        setName(UName);
        setFname(Ufname);
    }
}
```

And then the he problems occur in my other class called Admin:

```
public class Admin extends User {  //error "Implicit super constructor User() is undefined for default constructor. Must define an explicit constructor"

//public Admin() { } //tried to add empty constructor but error stays there

    //}


    public void manage_items() {            

        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    public void manage_users() {   

        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

I am getting the error `Implicit super constructor User() is undefined for default constructor. Must define an explicit constructor at the place marked in the code.` I don't know how to fix that, and I'm really new to java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must call the `Visitor`'s constructor on the first like of the constructor that extends the `Visitor`'s class, using `super()`:

```
public User(String UName,String Ufname){
    super();
    setName(UName);
    setFname(Ufname);
}
```

and if you want Admin to have a custom constructor too, you must call:

```
super(uname, ufname) // String, String - pass the params of the superclass cunstructor
```

So:

```
public Admin() {
    super(someString, someString);
}
```

Comment: errors remains there.Visitor doesnt have a constructor.It doesnt need one,and admin doesnt need one too

Comment: @Phil_oneil You are wrong, as you can see, User does have a constructor, so it is required to call it in any classes that extend User

Comment: Like I said im really new to java and I added what you told me too but the error remains there.I added visitor class in case needed

Comment: @Phil_oneil what exactly is the error? can you please provide it?

Comment: I modified admin to "public class Administrateur extends Utilisateur {  
 public Administrateur() { 
     super();
 } "    and I get the error "The constructor User() is undefined at the super() part

Comment: @Phil_oneil In admin, you must pass 2 strings, so like super("string1", "string2");
It can't be empty like "super()"

Comment: @Phil_oneil Just like I showed in the answer code :). try copy-pasting it

Comment: `You must call the Visitor's constructor` and why he has to do that?

Comment: @Victor2748 AAAH i got it now thanks :) However,what would be better? passing value like you do or creating an empty constructor public User(){} and then writing super() in admin? Considering my admin names etc.. are hardcoded in the program so no need to set "names" to them and stuff like that

Comment: @Phil_oneil That REALLY depends on: what you are trying to achieve, and what coding patterns you follow. I don't know your full code story here, but I would suggest to leave it like in the answer, have the constructors taking in the names.

Comment: @Phil_oneil Yeah, I think the best way is to make the constructor taking in the names (just like in the answer), instead of having it blank.

Comment: I still would like to know why OP should call the existing non-argument constructor manually :).

Comment: @Phil_oneil You mean, why is it required to do "super()" even if it has no arguments?

Comment: Since I know that it is *not* required, yes I'd like to know, why you wrote that. And no, I'm not Phil_oneil.

Comment: @Tom oh lol :D, well, a class can have a constructor that takes in NO params, but still has code inside it. So if the superclass does not override the default constructor, it is optional, but if it does, it IS required.

Comment: @Tom It is always good to write "super()", even if the super-class does not override the default constructor yet. So it will be easily-maintainable, if you suddenly override the default constructor, you won't have to write "super()" in every class that extends it.

Comment: Your info is wrong. It is never required to call `super()` and calling that "always good" is a matter of code style, nothing else. It is not necessary to call `super()` manually since calling the parent constructor is *always* the first thing a child constructor does and obvious code should be omitted to avoid code clutter. And no, it is not required to call `super()` manually if the parent class only has an overloaded constructor (it is called overload and not override), because this call would fail.

Comment: @Tom My info is 100% right, and even though calling "super()" when a superclass does not have a constructor is optional, I would still do it *most* of the time, because it is is a good practice for big projects.

Comment: @Victor2748 Ok, if you still think, that is right, I'll leave you there. And whoever taught you that this is a good practice to clutter the code ... well, I don't want to see his code.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't add a constructor to a class, one is automatically added for you. For the Admin class, it will look like this:

```
public Admin() { 
    super();
}
```

The call super() is calling the following constructor in the parent User class:

```
public User() {
    super();
}
```

As this constructor does not exist, you are receiving the error message.

See here for more info on default constructors:
 http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html

> You don't have to provide any constructors for your class, but you must be careful when doing this. The compiler automatically provides a no-argument, default constructor for any class without constructors. This default constructor will call the no-argument constructor of the superclass. In this situation, the compiler will complain if the superclass doesn't have a no-argument constructor so you must verify that it does. If your class has no explicit superclass, then it has an implicit superclass of Object, which does have a no-argument constructor.*

Comment: When calling superclass of Admin, you must pass the valid params, instead of leaving the brackets empty.

Comment: Please fix the arguments when calling the superclass constructor, your answer is wrong.

Comment: but my user does have a constructor I cant just leave remove the parameters public User() theres arguments that needs to stay there

Comment: @Phil_oneil I have answered why you are receiving the error message. See Elliott Frisch's answer for possible solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Your `Admin` class extends `User`, and `User` doesn't have a default construtor. You need to use the constructor that takes two `String`(s) with `super`. Something like,

```
public Admin() {
  super("a", "b"); // <-- first line.
}
```

Alternatively, you could add a no-args constructor to `User`

```
public User() {
}
```

And then your current `Admin` would compile.

Answer (score 2):

You need to know two things:

1. At start of each constructor there is call to constructor of superclass. It is represented by

   - `super()` - invoke no-argument constructor of superclass
   - `super(your,arguments)` - invoke constructor handling arguments with same types as passed to `super(..)`.

   If we want to use no-argument constructor we don't actually need to write `super()` because compiler will add code representing call to `super()` in binaries, but compiler can't do this nice thing for us if we want to call `super` with arguments because

   - it can't decide which constructor with arguments of superclass you want to use,
   - and what values (arguments) should be passed there,

   so in that case you need to explicitly write `super(your,arguments)` at start of your constructor yourself.
2. If you will not add any constructor to your class compiler will add *default constructor*, which will have no arguments and its only instruction will be calling no-argument constructor of superclass `super()`. In other words code of classes like

   ```
   class Base{}
   class Derived extends Base{}
   ```

   is same as this code

   ```
   class Base extends Object{
       Base(){
           super();//will try to call Object() constructor
       }
   }
   class Derived extends Base{
       Derived(){
           super();//will try to call Base() constructor
       }
   }
   ```

Now since in `User` class there is only one constructor `User(String UName,String Ufname)` when you try to compile

```
public class Admin extends User {  

    public void manage_items() {            
        //...
    }

    public void manage_users() {   
        //...
    }
}
```

compiler see it as

```
public class Admin extends User {  

    public Admin(){
        super();
    }

    public void manage_items() {            
        //...
    }

    public void manage_users() {   
        //...
    }
}
```

Now as you see problem lies in

```
    public Admin(){
        super();
    }
```

because `super()` will try to invoke no-argument `User()` constructor, but there is no such constructor because only existing constructor in `User` class is `User(String,String)`.

So to make this work you need to add `Admin` constructor and at its start call `super(someString, someString)`.

So consider adding to your `Admin` class constructor like this one:

```
 public Admin(String aName,String Afname){
     super(aName, Afname);
     //here you can place rest of your constructors code
 }
```